# java.nio.channels.AsynchronousClose Exception on Java 8

Tags: java, file, asynchronous, filechannel

I just moved my code from java 7 windows to java 1.8 Linux and i am getting this stack trace on same code base

> java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
>           at sun.nio.ch.SimpleAsynchronousFileChannelImpl$3.run(SimpleAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java:380) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]

My codes is as below

```
  Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        byte[] inputBytes = jsonString.getBytes(cs);
        fileChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(inputBytes), 0, ByteBuffer.wrap(inputBytes),new CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>() {

            @Override
            public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment) {
                log.info("Async Saving site content completed for sitename");
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                log.error("Async File Write Failed",exc);
                log.fatal(exc);
            }
        });
```

Wonder what is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you think the javadoc of [`AsynchronousCloseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousCloseException.html) might be a hint of potential cause? *Checked exception received by a thread when **another thread closes the channel** or the part of the channel upon which it is blocked in an I/O operation.*

Comment: The same code worked fine when built on Java 1.7 and windows. Not sure what changed with 1.8 and Linux.

Comment: It is very likely a multi threading issue rather than a java version or platform type issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment i took a second look and the above code was enclosed in a try catch with a finally statement that has a FileStream "close" method call. Culprit is that finally statement closes the channel when the other thread is writing into the channel.

I removed the finally block and moved the close file stream code into completion handler and it works now.

Note : How it worked in windows still eludes me. The code is still deployed in Windows servers and right before i write this , i retested and it works with the finally block in there :). Anyways wont spend any more time on this.

Marking it resolved. Thanks a lot for all the pointers.